# Compiling the same files twice programatically in C# throws "Could not find part of path" error

Tags: c#, codedom

I'm using C# and CodeDOM to compile code programatically by exporting CodeDOM representations to strings and using

```
Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
ICodeCompiler compiler = provider.CreateCompiler();
```

To create a usable compiler. After compiling a batch of programs, represented as strings, I then filter out any programs which had compile errors and remake the program batch with a new array of strings. I then feed this into a newly instantiated compiler.

This error is always thrown at the end of compilation:

> Could not find a part of the path
>   "/var/folders/hq/khn2hhc90ndfds54466xgd0h0000gn/T/18cf8079/19d1d18e.dll".

The file path is different each time, presumably because we're not using actual files but strings of program code. I have no idea what is causing this at all. The programs are all fine, there's a new compiler from a new provider. I can't think of any side effects the first batch of compilation would have. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide the exact usage in your code?

Comment: Considering the path, are you using mono?

Comment: If you don't specify an `Output` for your `CompilerParameters` a random name will be used.